# Hyperledger Besu - User Account Management

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, account, hyperledger-besu

I have recently started to learn the Hyperledger Besu, and what I am trying to do is actually compare Besu with Fabric and see if it is compatible with my already finished Fabric project.

I know from Fabric that using the CA from an organization we can create new users that are under that org. Also, there is the option to name this user with a username and add some custom attributes that can be used in the chaincode like `attribute role` for example.

Now, in Besu I have only discovered so far that only with some third party tools like MetaMask and the js library web3j we can create accounts. Although, those accounts are in the form of `Public Key/Address` & `Private Key`.

Is there something that I have missed out?
Is it possible to have somehow similar user accounts in Besu like Fabric?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my own research I have concluded that these are the only ways to create accounts for Hyperledger Besu:
`MetaMask Wallet`

`web3 js library through javascript`

In order to have more specific accounts that may be connected with some user information or roles that could determine various things in the application, the most suitable option is the following:

Use a centralized database to store the user information and associate it with the users address. This database could be used from a client application where the user can login with his/her credentials or using a third-party wallet like MetaMask.

Also, to distinguish the users inside the smart contracts the best option so far seems to be the library of OpenZeppelin `Ownable`